# Sending an Post Request of an Array using Volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am relatively new to android and I am trying to send an array to a rails server in the form

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"jackson", "email"=>"jack@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",        "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

I don't know if i am doing it correctly but here is what I have. I have a User class to save the data

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String password_confirmation;

        public User(String name, String email, String password, String password_confirmation) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.password_confirmation = password_confirmation;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
            return password_confirmation;
        }

        public void setPasswordConfirmation(String password_confirmation) {
            this.password_confirmation = password_confirmation;
        }

}
```

I then get the input using

```
inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_username);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd);
    inputPasswordConfirmation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd_confirm);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final User user = new User(null, null, null, null);
            user.setName(String.valueOf(inputUsername.getText()));
            user.setEmail(String.valueOf(inputEmail.getText()));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(inputPassword.getText()));
            user.setPasswordConfirmation(String.valueOf(inputPasswordConfirmation.getText()));
```

Now where I am stuck is making the post request. I have tried sending the email using

```
protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email",email);
                    return params;
                }
```

but that sends data as `{"email"=>"example@gmail.com"}` Instead of `"user"= {"name"=>"example@gmail.com"}`

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user.put("email",email);
    params.put("user", user);
    return params;
 }
```

Comment: When I try the above I get an error that `Return type is incompatible with Request<string>.getParams()`

Comment: oh yes sorry, i changed the return type, the map should be a Map<String, Map<String, String>>.

Comment: Would I have to do the same to include name, password and password confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your data into a `JSONObject` and use it as the body of the request. Something along the lines of this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

// populate JSON with the user data

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // your implementation
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           // your implementation
        }
    });
```

But before you try it I must give you some slightly off-topic advice:

1. Do not create multiple instances of `RequestQueue`. The intended pattern is a single `RequestQueue` to handle all of your network needs. That's why many choose the singleton pattern.
2. Your Java naming conventions are inaccurate and inconsistent. You should read about. Try searching for it, or try this [link](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html).
3. Calling a constructor with 4 `null` variables is bad style. I recommend reading up on Java if you are a beginner. A good place to start IMO is "Effective Java".

I hope I didn't discourage you, I just want to give you some insight since you are relatively new.

Good luck.